# (JQUERY) I want to make an invisible div visible on click and hide it again onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

So i have a trouble in which i want to make my invisible "container" visible when i click on my "input type='submit'" and then close it again when i click on close but i cant seem to get it working.
HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#"><span id="close"><em>x</em></span></a>
<div id="wrapper">
    <font id="wrapper-text"><em>Upload Your Own Video!</em></font>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title for the video"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="User"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Tags"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Description for the video" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {display:none; height:707px; widht:100%; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3)}
```

Script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById('#yourown').click(function(){
        document.getElementById("#container").css("display","block");
            )} 
        )}
     $document.ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("#close").click(function{
            document.getElementById("#container").css("display","none")
        })
     })
```

Comment: Use `#` with `$()`, not with `document.getElementById`. You don't have an element with the ID of `yourown` so that function won't work. You also can't do `document.getElementById(...).click`. Open your error console (hit F12) and that will give you a good idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Ops, i must have missed to put it in code where i make the ID of "yourown" in the post but i have it in my code :)

Comment: You really need to study some basic jQuery tutorials and learn to use browser console to check for errors

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery then the use of `document.getElementById()` is incorrect.
Just use this:

```
$("#yourown").click(function(){
    $("#container").toggle();
});
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#container").hide();
});
```

Comment: Okey, thanks for the tip. And as you might see i am quite new to the whole coding world but i am trying to learn as good as i can:)

Comment: And i for what i want (if you can see the album) http://imgur.com/a/Kjy1H when you click on the "upload video" on the first image the container should pop up like on the 2:nd image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you probably want to use $('#container').show() and $('#container').hide().

I'd recommend reading up on them [here:](http://api.jquery.com/)

You're also missing some semicolons... Something like this should work:

```
    $('#yourown').click(function(){ 
        $("#container").show(); 
    });
    $("#close").click(function{ 
        $("#container").hide();
    });
```